# Multiple calls to Ajax instead of once

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the following code which works fine for most cases, but the problem I am having is on mouse over . After you hover for 10 sec the content expands and then calls ajax. The Ajax is making calls 5 times instead of just once.

I am not sure why its keep calling 5 times.  Can someone help me fix this so ajax call runs only once?

Here is my code snippet below and the full working [fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dev2020/qrxfgvpq/2/) is here

```
$(".previewCard-content").hide();
var timeo = null;
$("body").on("mouseenter", ".previewCard-showhide", function() { // Use rather mouseenter!
    var $that = $(this); // Store the `this` reference
    clearTimeout(timeo); // Clear existent timeout on m.Enter 

    timeo = setTimeout(function() { // Before setting a new one
        $that.hide().closest('p').next(".previewCard-content").slideDown("slow");

        /**************** AJAX CALL********************/
        var LinkTextVal = $that.closest('.previewCard-b').find('.previewCardPageLink').text();
        console.log(" LinkTextVal  " + LinkTextVal);
        var descPageName = LinkTextVal + ' | About';
        if ($('#userID').val() !== '' && $('#userID').val() !== undefined && $('#userID').val() !== null) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/localhost/biz/actions/searchBookmark' + '?cachestop=' + nocache,
                type: "get",
                data: {
                    bookmarkName: descPageName
                },
                success: function(response) {
                    if (response === true) {
                        $that.parents('.previewCard-b').find('.save a').addClass('saved');
                        $that.parents('.previewCard-b').find('.save a').addClass('active');
                        $that.parents('.previewCard-b').find('.save a').find(".action-text").text("Saved");
                    }

                },
                error: function(e) {
                    console.log('Unable to check if a bookmark exists for the user.');
                }
            });
        }
        /***************** END AJaX/SAVE BUTTON ************/

    }, 1000);
}).on("mouseleave", ".previewCard-showhide", function() { // mouse leaves? Clear the timeout again!
    clearTimeout(timeo);
});
$(".close-btn").on("click", function() {
    var $itemB = $(that).closest(".previewCard-b");
    $itemB.find(".previewCard-content").slideUp();
    $itemB.find(".previewCard-showhide").show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Mouse hover events happen every time the mouse moves over the element. You need is to have a `boolean` which checks if you have sent the `AJAX` Request or not, and if it hasn't send the `AJAX` request, else ignore the event.

```
$(".previewCard-content").hide();
var timeo = null;
var ajaxSent = false
$("body").on("mouseenter", ".previewCard-showhide", function() { // Use rather mouseenter!
    var $that = $(this); // Store the `this` reference
    clearTimeout(timeo); // Clear existent timeout on m.Enter 

    timeo = setTimeout(function() { // Before setting a new one
        $that.hide().closest('p').next(".previewCard-content").slideDown("slow");

        /**************** AJAX CALL********************/
        var LinkTextVal = $that.closest('.previewCard-b').find('.previewCardPageLink').text();
        console.log(" LinkTextVal  " + LinkTextVal);
        var descPageName = LinkTextVal + ' | About';
        if ($('#userID').val() !== '' && $('#userID').val() !== undefined && $('#userID').val() !== null && !ajaxSent) {
            ajaxSent = true;
            $.ajax({
                url: '/localhost/biz/actions/searchBookmark' + '?cachestop=' + nocache,
                type: "get",
                data: {
                    bookmarkName: descPageName
                },
                success: function(response) {
                    if (response === true) {
                        $that.parents('.previewCard-b').find('.save a').addClass('saved');
                        $that.parents('.previewCard-b').find('.save a').addClass('active');
                        $that.parents('.previewCard-b').find('.save a').find(".action-text").text("Saved");
                    }

                },
                error: function(e) {
                    console.log('Unable to check if a bookmark exists for the user.');
                }
            });
        }
        /***************** END AJaX/SAVE BUTTON ************/

    }, 1000);
}).on("mouseleave", ".previewCard-showhide", function() { // mouse leaves? Clear the timeout again!
    clearTimeout(timeo);
});
$(".close-btn").on("click", function() {
    var $itemB = $(that).closest(".previewCard-b");
    $itemB.find(".previewCard-content").slideUp();
    $itemB.find(".previewCard-showhide").show();
});
```